# Read serial using Python but getting no result

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I try to write a hex string from Raspberry Pi to Fingerprint Identification Module ZFM-20 and read the response of this module.

This is manual:

[image]

Follow the manual, when I write hex string = EF01FFFFFFFF010003010005 (Address default = FFFFFFFF), the fingerprint will response ACK package.

I implement this with Python, but I have a trouble. It seems to have response me, but I can not print the result.

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from binascii import hexlify

serial=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",
                 baudrate=57600,
                 stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                 parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                 bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                 timeout=0.1)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
strGenImg = "\xEF\x01\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x01\x00\x03\x01\x00\x05"
Address = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
#$strGenImg = "\xEF\x01" + Address + "\x01\x00\x03\x01\x00\x05"
serial.write(strGenImg)
data=serial.readline()
print type(data)
print data
```

And this is result, I can't print:

[image]

Comment: When you debug, you should **ALWAYS** (in my humble opinion) encapsulate the thing you want to print. For instance : `print '[{}]'.format(3) # outputs : [3]`. The reason is simple : If you have an empty string, such as `''`, you would then print `[]`.

Comment: Here, you have 2 prints. One prints the type(), and the other one, the data. I believe you are actually printing the data as `print` automatically makes a newline (`'\n'`) when called. if you comment the `print data`, you would have one less line (the empty one)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, let me try.